# How to hide an entire class without creating errors

Tags: javascript, html, css, typeerror

I'm tried to create something that makes a quiz. I tried to make each 'part' of the quiz open when I start or answer a question.
This is part 1 and 2 of the quiz.

```js
function begin() {
  var b = document.getElementsByClassName("part2")
  var b2 = 0
  while (b.length >= b2) {
    b[b2].style.visibility = "visible";
    b2 += 1;
  }
  return b
}
    function q1nextcorrect(){
        document.getElementById("q1correctwrong").innerHTML="yes!"
    
        
    }
    function q1nextwrong(){
        document.getElementById("q1correctwrong").innerHTML="no"
    }
```

```css
.part2{
        visibility: collapse;
    }
```

```html
<part1 class="part1">
  <h1 style="text-align: center" class="part1">Hello!</h1>
  This is a test. No pressure. Ok! Have fun!
  <div class="part1"></div>
  <button class="part1" onclick="begin()">Begin!</button>
  <div class="part1"></div>
</part1>
<part2 class="part2">
  1+1=?
  <div class="part2"></div>
  <button class="part2" onclick="q1nextwrong()">1</button>
  <button class="part2" onclick="q1nextcorrect()">2</button>
  <p class="part2" id="q1correctwrong"></p>
</part2>
```

It works. However it throws errors:`{ "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined", "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js", "lineno": 31, "colno": 11 }`
How does it work and why does it throw errors?

Comment: Arrays are zero-based. The last element is at index `array.length - 1`. Your `while` loop tries to access an element at index `array.length` -> `undefined`. `>=` should be `>`

Comment: `.querySelectorAll(".part2").forEach(...)` would be an easier and fail-proof version of your `while`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
while (b.length >= b2) {
    b[b2].style.visibility = "visible";
    b2 += 1;
  }
```

To

```
for (var x = 0; x < b.length; x++ ) {
    b[x].style.visibility = "visible";
  }
```

*Snippet 1*

```js
function begin() {
  var b = document.querySelectorAll(".part2")
  for (var x = 0; x < b.length; x++ ) {
    b[x].style.visibility = "visible";
  }
  return b
}
    function q1nextcorrect(){
        document.getElementById("q1correctwrong").innerHTML="yes!"
    
        
    }
    function q1nextwrong(){
        document.getElementById("q1correctwrong").innerHTML="no"
    }
```

```css
.part2{
        visibility: collapse;
    }
```

```html
<part1 class="part1">
  <h1 style="text-align: center" class="part1">Hello!</h1>
  This is a test. No pressure. Ok! Have fun!
  <div class="part1"></div>
  <button class="part1" onclick="begin()">Begin!</button>
  <div class="part1"></div>
</part1>
<part2 class="part2">
  1+1=?
  <div class="part2"></div>
  <button class="part2" onclick="q1nextwrong()">1</button>
  <button class="part2" onclick="q1nextcorrect()">2</button>
  <p class="part2" id="q1correctwrong"></p>
</part2>
```

*Snippet 2:* Same in a easy way

```js
document.querySelector("[beginN]").addEventListener("click", begin);
function begin() {
  var b = document.querySelector(".p2");
  b.classList.toggle("d-none");
}
const answers = document.querySelector("#answers");
const a = answers.querySelectorAll("button");

for(var x = 0; x < a.length; x++){
  a[x].addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(this.getAttribute("val") == 2)
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Hooray!";
    else
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Failed!";

  });
}
```

```css
.d-none{ display:none; }
```

```html
<div class="p1">
  <h1 style="text-align: center">Hello!</h1>
    This is a test. No pressure. Ok! Have fun!
    <button beginN>Begin!</button>
</div>
<div class="p2 d-none">
  1 + 1 = ? <br>
  <div id=answers>
  ? =
          <button val="1">1</button>
          <button val="2">2</button>
      </div>
  <p id=result></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why should OP change the `while` to a `for` loop? The only problem is the condition.

Comment: I think the `for` loop looks a bit more complicated. I'll stick the `while` loop with the fixed condition :)

Comment: I don't know much about `while` loop,  Anyway `for` loop is much easier for me